# How a facade object notifies that it's contents have changed in WPF

Tags: c#, notifications, facade

I've put together a sample project for this: https://github.com/imekon/FacadeTest

The façade object contains the original object with a string variable called 'Thing'. When Thing is altered in the original object, the façade object should change, however without extra code, WPF doesn't notice the change.

The bit that concerns me is here:

```
public FacadeViewModel(DataViewModel data)
{
    m_data = data;

    m_data.PropertyChanged += (o, n) =>
    {
        if (n.PropertyName == "Thing")
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Thing));
        }
    };
}
```

This makes the project work - the second text box correctly updates as the original object updates, but it seems to me there should be a better way?

Comment: Does you question focus on `n.PropertyName == "Thing"`? Or what do you mean by *there should be a better way*?

Comment: I wasn't focussing on the n.PropertyName == "Thing", more the way I fixed it by using a handler in that way. It just felt wrong somehow.

Comment: I'm no WPF hero, but from my understanding that seems to be okay: you want to be notified whenever a property of your original object gets modified. For this, you have to subscribe to an event of the original object - what you're correctly doing.